# How to count various capitilizations of a phrase embedded in a string in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out how many capitalization variants I have in a bunch of rows of long strings and how many of each of them there are.

if I've a table of id's and value's and embedded in the value somewhere in a long string is a phrase I'm looking for "One Two Three Four".  The phrase could be absent, in the middle, beginning or end of value, repeated or different variants in the same line or multiple variants in the same line.

For example with the following table:

```
create table #tt (id int,myvalue varchar(500))
insert into #tt (id,myvalue) values
(1,'one two three four'),
(2,'One Two Three Four this is a long one Two Three four string I'm searching One Two Three Four')
```

I want a count of how many times a capitalization variation occurs (for examples:)

```
Variation           Count
one two three four  1
One Two Three Four  2
one Two Three four  1
```

The current collation is not case sensitive.

How would I go about this?

Comment: so, to reiterate, you're looking for a SPECIFIC substring that could appear 0 to N times in a string, and you want to COUNT the distinct/unique instances of this string?

Comment: count of (unknown amount of) variations of capitilization of a distinct string within other strings where any variation can show 0 to n times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this IS possible in SQL Server, but it will NOT scale very well.  I highly recommend taking this logic and converting it into a higher level language, like python, C#, etc.

```
declare @data table (Strings varchar(max))


insert into @data (Strings) values ('one two three four')
insert into @data (Strings) values ('one two three four One two three four one two three four')
insert into @data (Strings) values ('one two three four')
insert into @data (Strings) values ('one two three four')
insert into @data (Strings) values ('exclude')
insert into @data (Strings) values ('exclude one two three FOur exclude')




declare @search_string varchar(max),
    @search_len int

set @search_string = 'one two three four'
set @search_len = len(@search_string)





declare @matches table (ID int identity(1, 1), Strings varchar(max)) --store values to be processed
declare @extracts table (Strings varchar(max)) --values that we will extract

insert into @matches (Strings)
select Strings
from @data
where Strings like '%' + @search_string + '%'


declare @i int,
    @current int, @cnt int

select @i = count(*) from @matches where Strings like '%' + @search_string + '%'



while @i > 0
begin

    select @current = min(ID) from @matches

    insert into @extracts (Strings)
    select
        substring(Strings, charindex(@search_string, Strings), @search_len)
    from @matches
    where id = @current

    update @matches
    set Strings = stuff(Strings, charindex(@search_string, Strings), @search_len, '')
    where id = @current

    select @cnt = count(*)
    from @matches
    where id = @current
        and Strings like '%' + @search_string + '%'

    if (@cnt = 0)
    begin
        delete from @matches where id = @current
    end

    select @i = count(*) from @matches where Strings like '%' + @search_string + '%'
end


select 
    Strings collate latin1_general_cs_as, count(*)
from @extracts
group by Strings collate latin1_general_cs_as
```

Comment: I was thinking it would be easiest to do it case insensitive any match the later post processing process the strings themselves to extract counts.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just force the collation in select and group by....

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tt') is not null drop table #tt

create table #tt (C1 varchar(500))
insert into #tt (C1) values
('one two three four'),

('One two three four'),
('One two three four'),

('ONE two THREE four'),
('ONE two THREE four'),
('ONE two THREE four'),
('ONE two THREE four'),
('One Two Three Four this is a long one Two Three four string Im searching One Two Three Four')

select C1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, count(*) as ct from #tt
group by C1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

**EDIT**

IMHO, this should be done with Python, or JS or some other scripting language on your application side. It isn't what SQL Server is made for. I also can't think of a clean, dynamic way to do this. A cursor could get real out of hand and since you only provide some unrealistic test data, it's hard to scale a solution, but here is a way to do it with fixed, known variations that you are searching for.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tt') is not null drop table #tt
create table #tt (id int,myvalue varchar(500))
insert into #tt (id,myvalue) values
(1,'one two three four'),
(2,'One Two Three Four this is a long one Two Three four string Im searching One Two Three Four')

declare @FirstToCount varchar(50)
declare @SecondToCount varchar(50)
declare @ThirdToCount varchar(50)


set @FirstToCount = 'one two three four'
set @SecondToCount = 'One Two Three Four'
set @ThirdToCount = 'one Two Three four'

;with cte as(
select 
    @FirstToCount as Variation, (len(myvalue) - len(replace(myvalue COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,@FirstToCount COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,''))) / LEN(@FirstToCount) as CT
from #tt 
union all
select
    @SecondToCount, (len(myvalue) - len(replace(myvalue COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,@SecondToCount COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,''))) / LEN(@SecondToCount)as CT
from #tt 
union all
select  
    @ThirdToCount, (len(myvalue) - len(replace(myvalue COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,@ThirdToCount COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,''))) / LEN(@ThirdToCount)as CT
from #tt)


select 
    Variation COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
    sum(ct) as CT
from cte
group by Variation COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: This assumes all the strings listed are the values in the tables.  I've got long strings sometimes with different variations within the strings.  Simple collation would be easy.  If I've a string "One Two Three Four this is a long one Two Three four string I'm searching One Two Three Four" the first variation would list 2 counts and the middle variation one count.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean @gjutras? This is looking at string uniqueness... it doesn't use the `LIKE` operator that would throw false positives. I added your example to the data set above.

Comment: modified original question to clarify

Comment: Added another solution @gjutras

Comment: I agree that this sort of complex text analysis just isn't suited for sql.  it'd be better to pull it into another language and process it there.